# HTML5 Validator error

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, validation

I am trying to valid an HTML5 page against through the W3C validator and I'm getting an error that I can't find information on.  Does anyone have any experience of this error and how to overcome it?

This is the html element:

```
 <canvas id="eventCanvas" name="eventCanvas" width="1000" height="500" draggable="true"> </canvas>
```

This is the error from the validator: Attribute name not allowed on element canvas at this point. [HTML5]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means canvas cannot have a name attribute.

change your code to:

```
<canvas id="eventCanvas" width="1000" height="500" draggable="true"> </canvas>
```

and that error should go away.

Comment: I stupidly realised that and just took them all out and revalidated it. Sorry for being stupid.... Thanks for not laughing at me :-)